# Vertical Line and a circular view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to get a vertical line in-between ImageViews to showcase a flow.

Here is what I am trying to achieve,

[image]

Here is what I have now

[image]

Background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="44dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="44dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Item Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_item_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Group" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

`Is there a better way to do this` **Yes**.

You can use a TextView to include the left Image, and save yourself a View for every row, by simply using a compound drawable:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_item_bg"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/circle"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Group"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To set the drawable via code, use setCompundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

You might also want to add some top and bottom margin to the vertical line and make the background color transparent, instead of white (so you can use it also on a dark container background color).